# Eye of gnome (eog) open image in the same instance

Tags: bash, gnome

I'm trying to open one image using eye of gnome, input a delay and then have a second image open using the same instance of eye of gnome.

```
#!/bin/bash
eog test1.jpg
sleep 5 
eog test2.jpg
```

This effectively opens test1.jpg, waits 5 seconds and then opens test2.jpg but it opens test2.jpg as a second instance of eog.

Long term I'm wondering if I can write a bash script to act like the slideshow but without being fullscreen and pulling images from multiple folders.

Comment: @Cyrus doesn't --new-instance do exactly the opposite of what is wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the --single-window option of eog:

> -w, --single-window       Open in a single window, if multiple
>   windows are open the first one is used

So your script could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
eog test1.jpg &
sleep 5
eog --single-window test2.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, that does it. Sorry for the silly question. I did check the -help. Turns out I was using an old version of eog which did not have the --single-window as an option.